# Is it possible to operate on the aggregated dcast values?

Tags: r, data.table, dcast

dcast.data.table has the feature to aggregate on multiple value.var. Is it possible to somehow reference the aggregated values being created and then perform an operation within the fun ?

This creates the 4 variables

```r
DT = data.table(x=sample(5,20,TRUE), y=sample(2,20,TRUE),
                z=sample(letters[1:2], 20,TRUE), d1 = runif(20), d2=1L)

> head(DT)
   x y z        d1 d2
1: 3 2 a 0.6166590  1
2: 3 1 a 0.1891611  1
3: 5 2 a 0.3061658  1
4: 3 1 a 0.7233832  1
5: 2 1 b 0.6799675  1
6: 2 1 b 0.5144392  1

dcast(DT, x + y ~ z, fun=sum, value.var=c("d1", "d2"))

   x y      d1_a      d1_b d2_a d2_b
1: 1 1 1.0400277 0.3835004    2    1
2: 2 1 0.7032111 1.3713884    1    2
3: 3 1 0.9759893 2.0853103    1    3
4: 3 2 0.5210792 0.0000000    1    0
5: 4 1 1.0971931 0.4417819    2    1
6: 4 2 0.5009533 0.0000000    1    0
7: 5 1 0.9372943 0.0000000    4    0
8: 5 2 0.7671728 0.0000000    1    0
```

And the operation(s) on the aggregated values can be performed in the second step

```r
dcast(DT, x + y ~ z, fun=sum, value.var=c("d1", "d2"))[,.(div1 = d1_a/d2_a
                                                          ,div2 = d1_b/d2_b)]

        div1      div2
1: 0.5200139 0.3835004
2: 0.7032111 0.6856942
3: 0.9759893 0.6951034
4: 0.5210792       NaN
5: 0.5485965 0.4417819
6: 0.5009533       NaN
7: 0.2343236       NaN
8: 0.7671728       NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit convoluted,
but for this problem I think you could do the following:

```
zs <- unique(DT$z)

sum_div <- function(dt) {
  ans <- dt[, .(div = sum(d1) / sum(d2)), by = .(z)]
  split(ans$div, factor(ans$z, levels = zs), drop = FALSE)
}

DT[, sum_div(.SD), by = .(x, y), .SDcols = c("z", "d1", "d2")]
```

What happens is that `.SD` ends up having the 3 columns specified in `.SDcols`,
but with different subsets for the possible combinations of `x` and `y` values.
Then, `sum_div` performs your desired operation only on that subset,
and `split`s the result to return a list so that each possible value of `z` gets its own column in the final `data.table`.

It's important to do `factor(ans$z, levels = zs)` in order to get the same number of list elements every time
(`data.table` expects that);
by specifying how many `levels` we expect,
`split` will return an empty vector if there are no values for a `level`,
but it will definitely return something for each.

Note that you could achieve the same with:

```
dcast(DT[, .(div = sum(d1) / sum(d2)), by = .(x, y, z)], x + y ~ z, value.var = "div")
```

I'm not sure if you gain considerable performance by doing everything in one step.

EDIT: you probably don't:

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

n <- 2e5
DT = data.table(x = sample(5L, n, TRUE),
                y = sample(3L, n, TRUE),
                z = sample(letters[1:2], n, TRUE),
                d1 = runif(n),
                d2 = 1L)

zs <- sort(unique(DT$z))

sum_div <- function(dt) {
  ans <- dt[, .(div = sum(d1) / sum(d2)), by = .(z)]
  split(ans$div, factor(ans$z, levels = zs), drop = FALSE)
}

microbenchmark(
  one = DT[, sum_div(.SD), keyby = .(x, y), .SDcols = c("z", "d1", "d2")],
  two = dcast(DT[, .(div = sum(d1) / sum(d2)), by = .(x, y, z)], x + y ~ z, value.var = "div"),
  times = 10L
)
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  one 24.37323 25.74273 26.72413 25.99279 26.62943 34.40309    10
  two 11.31050 11.91650 12.66345 12.51094 13.01364 15.35549    10
```